# LOAD DATA INFILE reads foreign key as a comma

Tags: mysql, file-io, command, load

I'm trying to load data into a sql table using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command. For testing purposes, my file only has one row, but in the future it will have many many more. The contents is, for now:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/users/jgonz/documents/myproject/labtxt.csv' INTO TABLE labevents FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ;
```

`17871279;60669;86433;50819;"2149-11-09 19:42:00";8.0;8.0;"nan";"nans"`

Where the second number, 60669 is a foreign key. When using `LOAD DATA INFILE` I get an error message stating a foreign key constraint fail, pointing at that column, but I know such id exists in the table it's pointing at. Furthermore, if I upload the same file using phpmyadmin's UI there is problem at all.

Trying to find the problem, I run the command `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`, and in the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` I found this

```
Foreign key constraint fails for table `openmrs`.`labevents`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `patient_id` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`patient_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

Does this mean it is reading the foreign id value as a comma (,)? If so, how? why? and how can I fix it?
I'm using windows 10 by the way

Comment: You need to show the full load data command you used and state your os.

Comment: Just added the full command, and found the problem in the process, I feel so dumb

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb, I just realized the problem

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/users/jgonz/documents/myproject/labtxt.csv' INTO TABLE labevents FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ;
```

The terminated by line should be a ';' instead of a ','